# Оптимизация подсчёта несовпадающих элементов двух массивов

Tags: c

Есть программа на Си, которая подсчитывает количество несовпадающих элементов двух массивов:

```
#include <stddef.h>
size_t arr_dist(size_t n, const char a[n], const char b[n]) {
  size_t result = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    result += a[i] != b[i];
  return result;
}
```

Каким образом можно оптимизировать скорость выполнения данной программы?

Comment: Задача именно в оптимизации скорости выполнения программы

Comment: А Вы профилировали или просто решили, что эта функция виновата? Ее можно ускорить, если использовать sse, но я думаю, что нужно смотреть "шире".

Comment: На моей машине сравнение двух массивов по миллиарду элементов вашим методом занимает примерно полсекунды. Машина не самая быстрая на свете :) Такое время критично?

Comment: Жаль, что не С++ :) Я [тут](https://gitlab.com/disputant/rustackoverflow/-/blob/master/exper/array_comp.cpp) сравнил (VC++ 2019) предложенный способ (390мс), `inner_product` из стандартной библиотеки (490мс) и распараллеленный `transform_reduce` оттуда же (140мс). Меня терзают смутные сомнения, что оптимизировать такой код вряд ли имеет смысл...

Answer (score 2):

Решил я в перерывах между тревогами попробовать оптимизировать этот код. Берем код

```
size_t arr_dist(size_t n, const char a[n], const char b[n]) {
  size_t result = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    result += a[i] != b[i];
  return result;
}
```

как основу. Так как в коде я виду конструкцию `const char a[n]`, то я предполагаю, что используется gcc. Дальнейшие замеры и тесты будут на gcc/clang.

Самое первое, что я сделал, это попробовал подключить openmp.

```
size_t arr_dist_mp(size_t n, const char a[n], const char b[n]) {
  size_t result = 0;
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:result)
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    result += a[i] != b[i];
  return result;
}
```

Но толи я не умею готовить openmp (для gcc нужно добавить параметр `-fopenmp`), но у меня получилось по скорости где то в раза два медленнее. Почитав детальнее, я понял, что видимо внутренний цикл у меня слишком маленький и по рекомендациям выделил внутренний цикл

```
size_t arr_dist_mp1(size_t n, const char a[n], const char b[n]) {
  #define SIZE 1000000
  size_t result = 0;
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:result)
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i+=SIZE)
    for (size_t j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
      result += a[i+j] != b[i+j];
    }
  return result;
}
```

Но ничего толком это не поменяло. Ок, сказал я себе. Применим тяжелую артелерию - sse. Я использовал вторую версию, потому что с ней код будет работать практически на любом x86_64. Получилось вот так

```
size_t arr_dist_sse(size_t n, const char a[n], const char b[n]) {
  size_t result = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i+=16) {
    __m128i x1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(a+i));
    __m128i x2 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(b+i));
    __m128i r = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(x1, x2);
    result += __builtin_popcount(_mm_movemask_epi8(r));
  }
  return n - result;
}
```

Ого, сказал я и давайте посмотрим на первые результаты

| name | result | time, s |
| --- | --- | --- |
| base | 99609989 | 0.28245 |
| openmp | 99609989 | 0.55218 |
| openmp2 | 99609989 | 0.59675 |
| sse | 99609989 | 0.06872 |

(комментарии - я тестировал на 100кк элементов, которые заполнялись случайным порядком, поэтому, от теста к тесту средняя колонка может будет меняться, но разные функции должны выдавать одинаковые результаты в пределах теста. Тестовая  машинка - старый сервачек, где находится процессор Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz).

в 4 раза быстрее на ровном месте. Круто же. Но потом я вспомнил, что я не указывал никаких опций для оптимизации. Исправимся. `gcc -O3 main.c -fopenmp`

| name | result | time, s |
| --- | --- | --- |
| base | 99609989 | 0.03494 |
| openmp | 99609989 | 0.06401 |
| openmp2 | 99609989 | 0.07796 |
| sse | 99609989 | 0.03862 |

Видно странность? базовый вариант и sse сравнялись. Вот и gcc.

ок, а давайте посмотрим на clang. (если будете тестить, то для убунты нужно доустановить libomp-dev, а gcc умеет "из коробки").

clang, без оптимизаций

| name | result | time, s |
| --- | --- | --- |
| base | 99609989 | 0.28044 |
| openmp | 99609989 | 0.72413 |
| openmp2 | 99609989 | 0.67469 |
| sse | 99609989 | 0.37775 |

sse вариант даже отстает. что то пошло не так. явно не так. Включим чуточку оптимизаций (`clang -O3 -fopenmp main.c`)

| name | result | time, s |
| --- | --- | --- |
| base | 99609989 | 0.09226 |
| openmp | 99609989 | 0.16055 |
| openmp2 | 99609989 | 0.15885 |
| sse | 99609989 | 0.13449 |

Похоже, по сравнению с gcc, clang не умеет таких оптимизаций (в 3 раза проигрывает). А с sse совсем никак. Но может готовить не умеем? добавим немного `clang -fopenmp main.c -O3 -march=native` и

| name | result | time, s |
| --- | --- | --- |
| base | 99609989 | 0.02328 |
| openmp | 99609989 | 0.16114 |
| openmp2 | 99609989 | 0.16035 |
| sse | 99609989 | 0.05990 |

обычная версия выиграла. да ещё как. А попробуем для gcc такое добавить и запустить (`gcc -fopenmp main.c -O3 -march=native`)

| name | result | time, s |
| --- | --- | --- |
| base | 99609989 | 0.02889 |
| openmp | 99609989 | 0.05447 |
| openmp2 | 99609989 | 0.04901 |
| sse | 99609989 | 0.02540 |

и тут gcc показал себя ещё как.

**Вывод.** Опции компиляции могут с наскока дать больше прирост (или соизмеримый) с ручной оптимизацией. Можно ли ещё ускорить? возможно, но даже при 0.025 сек на 100кк элементов получается 8 гигабайт в секунду (у нас массива два), а это 64гигабита в секунду. Возможно.

Для тех, кто решит побаловаться и потестить у себя (или меня покритиковать:) ), вот код. У него вывод странный, но это что бы для SO сразу табличку красивую, что бы просто копипастить и не форматировать вручную.

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <immintrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>

char* gen(int n) {
  char* r = malloc(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    r[i] = rand() % 256;
  }
  return r;
}


size_t arr_dist(size_t n, const char a[n], const char b[n]) {
  size_t result = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    result += a[i] != b[i];
  return result;
}

size_t arr_dist_mp(size_t n, const char a[n], const char b[n]) {
  size_t result = 0;
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:result)
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    result += a[i] != b[i];
  return result;
}

size_t arr_dist_mp1(size_t n, const char a[n], const char b[n]) {
  #define SIZE 1000000
  size_t result = 0;
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:result)
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i+=SIZE)
    for (size_t j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
      result += a[i+j] != b[i+j];
    }
  return result;
}
size_t arr_dist_sse(size_t n, const char a[n], const char b[n]) {
  size_t result = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i+=16) {
    __m128i x1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(a+i));
    __m128i x2 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(b+i));
    __m128i r = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(x1, x2);
    result += __builtin_popcount(_mm_movemask_epi8(r));
  }
  return n - result;
}
void test(int n, const char* name, const char* a, const char* b, size_t(*func)(size_t, const char*, const char*)) {
  clock_t start = clock();
  size_t r = func(n, a, b);
  clock_t stop = clock();
  printf("| %10s | %10zu | %.5f |\n", name, r, (stop-start) * 1.f / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}

int main() {
  #define TEST_SIZE 100000000
  char* a = gen(TEST_SIZE);
  char* b = gen(TEST_SIZE);
  puts("|  name      |   result   | time, s |");
  puts("|------------|------------|---------|");
  test(TEST_SIZE, "base",    a, b, arr_dist);
  test(TEST_SIZE, "openmp",  a, b, arr_dist_mp);
  test(TEST_SIZE, "openmp2", a, b, arr_dist_mp1);
  test(TEST_SIZE, "sse" ,    a, b, arr_dist_sse);
  free(b);
  free(a);
}
```

Comment: КоVadim, огромное спасибо за проделанную работу. Просто респект, что еще сказать. Мое решение, которое привожу ниже, тоже базируется на использовании SSE2.
Все равно, Спасибо и еще раз "Респект за труд!". А налеты - это временно! Победа будет за нами!

Comment: у меня есть подозрение, что avx инструкции могут дать больше прирост - там можно будет не 128 битные регистры использовать, а 512 и считать разницу одной инструкцией, а не двумя. Но это нужно отдельно проверить. А какой у Вас "Типичный размер массива"?

Answer (score 0):

```
// SSE2 intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html
size_t arr_dist_best (size_t n, const char a [n], const char b [n]) { 
  size_t ub = n - (n % 16) ; 
 
  __m128i sums = _mm_setzero_si128 () ; 
  __m128i ones = _mm_set1_epi8 (1) ; 

  for (size_t i = 0; i < ub ; i += 16) { 
    __m128i as = _mm_loadu_si128 ((const __m128i_u *) & a [i]) ; 
    __m128i bs = _mm_loadu_si128 ((const __m128i_u *) & b [i]) ; 
    __m128i cs = _mm_cmpeq_epi8 (as, bs) ; 
    cs = _mm_andnot_si128 (cs, ones) ; // eq/ff -> 00; noteq /00 -> 01 
    cs = _mm_sad_epu8 (cs, _mm_setzero_si128 ()) ; 
    sums = _mm_add_epi64 (sums, cs) ; 
  } 
 
  size_t res = sums [0] + sums [1];
  for ( size_t i = ub ; i < n ; ++ i ) 
  res += a [ i ] != b [ i ]; 
  
  return res ; 
}
```

Comment: да, неплохо. в некоторых случаях лучше моего sse варианта в полтора раза. Я заметил, что на винде clang + openmp дает очень хорошие результаты. Очень.

Comment: Ничуть! Я вставил мое решение в предложенный тест и получил такой результат:

|  name            |   result        | time, s    |

|-------------------|-----------------|-------------|

|       base        |   99609989  | 0.25803 |

|     openmp     |   99609989  | 0.25578 |

|    openmp2    |   99609989  | 0.33896 |

| sse-KoVadim |   99609989  | 0.05819 |

|     sse-gk        |   99609989 | 0.06547  |

Comment: Все очень сильно зависит от процессора